# Is df.schema action or transformation?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a schema created manually for creating a dataframe say `myschema`
Now my dataframe say `df` is created.

Now, I did some operations on `df` and some of the columns were dropped. 
say original `myschema` consists of 500 columns 
Now after dropping some columns, my `df` consist of 450 columns.

Now somewhere in my code I need the schema back but only the schema after dataframe has applied some operations(ie. having 450 columns).

Now , 
Q1. How optimum is calling `df.schema` and using it, Is it action or transformation? 
Q2. Should I create another `myschema2` by filtering out those columns from `myschema`  which will be dropped  and use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answers:

to Q1: schema is neither an action neither a transformation, in the sense that it doesn't *modify* the *data frame* and doesn't trigger any computation.

to Q2:
 if I understand well, I guess you have something like this

```
val myschema = StructType(someSchema)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(someData, myschema)

// do some transformation (drop, add columns etc)
val df2 = df.drop("column1", "column2").withColumn("new", $"c1" + $"c2"))
```

and you want get the schema of df2. if it is so you can just use

```
val myschema2 = df2.schema
```

Long Answer: 
Informally speaking, DataFrame is an abstraction over distributed datasets, and as you already pointed out, there are transformations and actions *defined* on them.
When you *makes* some transformation on data frames, what happens under the hood is that spark just builds a *Directed Acyclic Graph* describing that transformations. When
That DAG is analyzed and used to **build** an execution plan to get the work done

Actions on the other hand *trigger* the execution of the plan, which is transforming the actual data.

Schema of a transformed data frame *is derived* from the schema of the initial data frame basically *walking* along the DAG. The impact of such derivations is _neglectable, it doesn't depend on the size of the data, it depends on how much *big* is the DAG, but in all practical cases, you can ignore the time required to get schema. Schema is just metadata attached to a dataframe.

So to respond to Q2: No you should not have schema2 taking track of the modification you. Just by calling df.schema Spark will do that for you

hope this clears your doubts

Comment: when you say df.schema is neither transformation and action, could you please elaborate its impact on performance. It doesn't trigger its computation then is the schema already save with the dataframe and if saved is it saved as an object in memory? just a concern ..

Comment: But one more thing.if that `df.schema` is under streaming section say, within every 3 minutes `df.schema` will be called and wont that impact performance as if you do a filter and keep that before hand and pass it accordingly ?

Comment: In general dataframe's schema can be  statically known, so there is no need to "recompute" even in case of streams